# Python -- Issues with method as parameter?

Tags: python, methods, syntax, parameters

I am  making a "Choose Your Adventure" game in Python.  As you will see in the code below, I have a method temporarily called unnamedMethod that has three parameters: a method, m; a string, ans1; and another string, ans2.

This method is supposed to handle the user's input derived from m and check to see if it equals one of two words.  If it doesn't equal either word, then it should print a simple error message ("Please submit a valid response.") and call the method m again.  However, I get the error message "str is not callable" with my current code.

Here is my project so far:

```
class player:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        self.inventory = []
        self.health = 10.0

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def printName(self):
        print("Your name is: " + self.name)

    def printInventory(self):
        print(self.inventory)


class game:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to Choose Your Adventure.")
        name = input("Please enter your name to begin: ")
        p = player(name)

    def intro(self):
        print("\n.....\n")
        ans = input("You awaken in a field skirted by a dense pine forest.\n" +
              "A rickety barn and its adjoining house lie a few hundred\n" +
              "feet ahead of you. Do you enter the forest or explore the\n" +
              "property? Type 'property' or 'forest': ")
        return ans

    def property(self):
        print("\n.....\n")
        print("You walked towards the property")

    def forest(self):
        print("\n.....\n")
        print("You walked into the forest")

    ###

    def unnamedMethod(self, m, ans1, ans2):
        ans = m() #where the error message occurs
        while ans.lower() != ans1 and ans.lower() != ans2:
            print("Please submit a valid response.")
            print("\n.....\n\n")
            ans = m()
        if ans.lower() == ans1:
            return ans1
        else:
            return ans2


class run:

    def __init__(self):
        g = game()
        print(g.unnamedMethod(g.intro(), "property", "forest"))


r = run()
```

If my code is running properly, it will loop through intro() until the user inputs "property" or "forest," and then it will print the corresponding word. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me find the issue with my code.

Comment: just `g.intro`, not `g.intro()` - you should be passing the method as a parameter, not calling it and passing the return value (a string) as the parameter.

Comment: You aren't passing a method as a parameter, you are passing a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g.intro()` returns a string, so all you need do is assign the returned value of the method which is passed as `m` to `ans`:

```
ans = m
```

If you want `m` to be treated as callable, then consider passing `g.intro` instead:

```
g.unnamedMethod(g.intro, "property", "forest")
...
ans = m()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ans=m(), trying to call the string m as a function, when I think you mean to set the value of ans to that of m, which can be done with the code ans=m.